# Is there a Better way to handle Same callback function but different input params?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, event-handling

I have a callback function to delete an li element.

```
function deleteLi(liElement) { 
   liElement.remove()
}
```

Two buttons does the same operation. On hovering the liElement, I get a edit & delete option. On clicking the edit option, it opens a dialog which also has a delete option. So both the buttons, does the same and hence I am calling the same function.

But it looks like this

```
$('.edit').on('click', function() {
     currentField = $(this).parents('li');
     openDialog();
});


$('.delete1').on('click', function() {
     deleteLi($(this).parents('li'));
});

$('.delete2').on('click', function() {
    deleteLi(currentField)
});
```

So is there any other best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply give a single class to both delete button 'delete1' and use following code

```
$('.delete1').on('click', function() {
     deleteLi($(this).parents('li'));
});
```

If your css if different for that delete button then multiple class selector in jQuery.

Edited the code as per the comments:

```
$('.delete1, .delete2').on('click', function() {
     if(currentField == null) {
         currentField = $(this).parents('li');
     }
     deleteLi(currentField);
});
```

Comment: Hi, The thing is I have different classes but I can't use ur answer bcoz for each class am passing a different parameter. .delete1 is inside the li so I can pass the parent li. But .delete2 is totally inside another div. I am passing the current selected li tag, by storing it in another variable

Comment: @Jazmin Ok, you can check that variable in second code section if currentField is 'undefined' then set $(this).parents('li') in that variable and passed it into 'deleteLi' method.
If not working then give me html :)

Comment: @Jazmin so according to this, the edit popup is inside the `<li>` as well..? If there are 100 `<li>`, there will be `100` unnecessary edit popups  ?

Comment: @TJ: Nope.. Edit popup is totally a different div which is common for all the <li>s. This is the final code

`$('.edit').on('click', function() {
     currentField = $(this).parents('li');
     openDialog();
});

$('.delete1, .delete2').on('click', function() {
     if(currentField == null) { 
         currentField = $(this).parents('li');
     }
     deleteLi(currentField);
});`

Comment: @Jazmin this is the same as what you were doing previously - you are storing the reference in a variable and using it. i don't see any improvements..

Comment: Also, the latest update will not work for the delete button in edit popup, since the edit popup is in a different `<div>`, `$(this).parents('li');` will be an empty jquery object... i wonder why this is the accepted answer..!

Comment: It would work, because whenever we open the edit popup, we assign the currentField as per the code in the question. 

And its a bit improved as the bindings for both the delete options are at one place.

Answer (score 0):

With this HTML:

```
<ul class="editableList">
  <li>
    <span>Stuff here</span>
    <a href="#" class="delete">-</a>
    <a href="#" class="edit">e</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Other stuff here</span>
    <a href="#" class="delete">-</a>
    <a href="#" class="edit">e</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And this J:

```
$('.editableList').on('click', '.delete', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent('li').remove()
}).on('click', '.edit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  editLi(this);
});

function editLi(elt) {
  // Code to edit "li > span" element
  console.log('editing element', elt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid thee global variable by adding a class (*or a data attribute, i'm using a class here for the visual feedback*) to the selected `<li>` on click of edit, and remove it once you close the edit popup:

```js
$('.edit').on('click', function () { // open edit popup
    $(this).closest('li').addClass("active"); // mark the current <li>
    $("#editPopup").show();
});

$("#editPopup span").on("click", function () { // close edit popup
    $(".active").removeClass("active"); // unselect it
    $("#editPopup").hide();
});

$('.delete').on('click', function () { // inline delete option
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
});

$('#delete').on('click', function () { // delete option in popup
    $(".active").remove();
    $("#editPopup").hide();
});
```

```css
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
}
li {
    border-bottom:1px solid;
    background:silver;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
}
li a {
    display:none;
    float:right;
    margin:0 5px;
}
li:hover a {
    display:inline-block;
}
li.active {
    background:dodgerblue;
}
#editPopup {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    margin:auto;
    background:#fff;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#editPopup span {
    position:absolute;
    right:5px;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:red;
}
#editPopup a {
    margin:5px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
li:first-child span{
    padding:3px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    color:#0077CC;
    outline:1px solid grey;
    background:white;
}
li:first-child span:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="editableList">
  <li> The <span>Full page</span> button is messing with my options!
      <a href="#" class="delete">x</a>
      <a href="#" class="edit">edit</a>
  </li>
  <li> <span>Item 2</span>
    <a href="#" class="delete">x</a>
    <a href="#" class="edit">edit</a>
  </li>
  <li> <span> Hover Me!</span>
    <a href="#" class="delete">x</a>
    <a href="#" class="edit">edit</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="editPopup"> <span>x</span><br/>
 <a href="#" id="edit">edit</a>
 <a href="#" id="delete">delete</a>
</div>
```

Comment: When the edit dialog window is opened and user click on delete, the dialog should be close.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use callback approach. When Edit button is hit, you define the currentField variable, and then define anonymous callback, which is called from openDialog's deleteButton.

```
$('.delete1').on('click', function () {
    deleteLi($(this).parents('li'));
});
$('.edit').on('click', function () {
    var currentField = $(this).parents('li');
    openDialog({
        onDelete: function () {
            deleteLi(currentField);
        }
    });
});
function openDialog(args) {
    //... open dialog here ...
    $('.delete2').on('click', args.onDelete);
}
```